# Association in Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a pretty simple model with a customer and Item, with one-to-many relation between them (One customer can have many items). I used the designer to place my entities and I do see an association between them in the designer. Its xml reflects this:

```
<Association Name="vgMfiCustomer_vgMfiItem" Member="vgMfiCustomer" ThisKey="CustomerLink" OtherKey="Customer" Type="vgMfiCustomer" IsForeignKey="true" />
```

Trouble is that in the designer.vb, there's no mention of this association, So I cannot say Customer.Items in my code. Did I miss a step in generating the model? Or maybe I need to add the navigation property manualy? I come from EF.NET background, where the navigation properties are created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the association setup for one direction, but not the other.  In the dbml, there should be an Association element for each type.  You may want to try removing the association in the designer and re-adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that both tables have a property marked as "Primary key" (in .dbml schema)